# how to set default group in grafana?

Tags: grafana, prometheus-operator

Instead of "Viewers" I would like the default grafana group to be "Editors".  I know about "viewers_can_edit" but would prefer to change the default group. I am deploying via prometheus-operator (to k8s).  Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Generally: there is config for that:

```
# Default role new users will be automatically assigned (if auto_assign_org above is set to true)
auto_assign_org_role = Viewer
```

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/8143991b9476bbc3a1e92636f01a9ba9c4a80a65/conf/defaults.ini#L307-L308

Of course it depends on used auth in Grafana. For example OAuth uses own role mapping.